# Why does this regex replace remove a symbol at the start, but not at the end?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove the apostrophes from this string: `"'234324234234234236548723adf83287942'"`.

I am trying to use this:

```js
var specialId = otherSpecialId[0].trim().replace(/^[']*$/,'');
```

to try and get `"234324234234234236548723adf83287942"`.

But I can’t seem to crack it. How do I remove the apostrophes (`'`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `'` on it's own with the global modifier:

```
var specialId = otherSpecialId[0].trim().replace(/'/g,'');
```

Alternatively, if the quotes are always at the start and end, you don't need to use a regex at all:

```
var specialId = otherSpecialId[0].trim().slice(1, -1);
```

- [*slice()* - MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

> *'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.'* — Jamie Zawinski

Comment: wow thanks a lot! never thought to use .slice(1, -1); thats a neat trick! :)

Comment: @Tom: yeah, `slice()` is a great function.  Its behaviour is more consistent across implementations than other substring functions :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `'` by nothing in that case. Currently you are replacing the whole string when it starts with a `'`.

So

```
.replace(/'/g,'');
```

might work. Or

```
.replace(/^'|'$/g,'');
```

if you only want to replace those in the start and end.

Comment: Both will only remove the first occurrence.  The `g` modifier is required if you want to replace multiple occurrences.

Comment: cool thanks a lot :) however @AndyE .slice(1, -1) is what I've used :)

Comment: Andy: Ah, thanks. I tend to work in languages where regexes are strings, not literals with modifiers baked into the syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
otherSpecialId[0].trim().replace(/'/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
var str = "'234324234234234236548723adf83287942'";
var rep = str.replace(/'/g,"");
alert(rep);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qyHth/

The `g` tells it to be greedy... and replace every instance of `'`.

Answer (score 1):

### replace(/'/g,"");

This replaces all **[ ' ]** with **Empty String**

**'/g'** is **global flag** and needed for replecement of all occurences **not only the first one**

[Working Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qceBc/)

```
var input = "\"'234324234234234236548723adf83287942'\"";

alert("Before replace :  " + input);

input = input.replace(/'/g,"");

alert("Aftwer replace :  " + input);
```